# If statement and multiple or conditions using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i check if somebody clicks any of the above id's (#transfers,#shopper,#tasks)
and then add a click event to an other button in order to activate it??

```
 <code><script>
$(function() {
    function updateServicesGroup(prop, value) {
        $('#Transfers').prop(prop, value);
        $('#Shopper').prop(prop, value);
        $('#Tasks').prop(prop, value)
    }
    var input = $('#services');
    var servicesGroup = $("#servicesGroup");
    input.on('change', function() {
        var isChecked = input.is(':checked')
        if (!isChecked) {
            updateServicesGroup('checked', false);
        }
        updateServicesGroup('enable', !isChecked)
        $(servicesGroup).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
   </script>
  <script>

$("#Transfers" ).click(function() {
    $('#services').click();
  });   

</script></code>
```

Comment: _add a click event to an other button in order to activate it?_ not getting it.

Comment: I tried to answer your question.  But then I realized that I can't even figure out what you're actually trying to do.  Slow down and be more descriptive.

Comment: @user..I suggest you to edit your profile and change your username. Coming to question, i am not able to understand what exactly you are asking..Take your time and frame your question neatly, that is the best to expect an answer from SO

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
 $("#transfers,#shopper,#tasks").click(function()
{
    $("#buttonid").click(function()
{
//your js code..
});

});
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I want to check if it clicks any of the above buttons to click and other button...its 3 checkboxes....but if the user click again any of the button not to click the other button

Answer (score 0):

use can use the trigger function for that,

```
$("#transfers,#shopper,#tasks").click(function(){
$( "#services" ).trigger( "click" );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("#transfers,#shopper,#tasks").click(function(){
   if($(this).attr('id')=="transfers")
     $("#services").trigger( "click" );
});
```

Comment: I want to check if it clicks any of the above buttons to click and other button...its 3 checkboxes....but if the user click again any of the button not to click the other button